# Update class instance StringVar() from abstract method

Tags: python-2.7, oop, methods, tkinter, instance-variables

I am trying to update 4 `StringVar()` with values read only after a file is opened. I'm trying to use an abstract method `set_values()` on the class `TestPage` to update the 4 `StringVar()`.

```
...

class TestPage(Tk.Frame):

    def __init__(self, parent, *controller):

        Tk.Frame.__init__(self, parent)

        self.x = Tk.StringVar()
        self.y = Tk.StringVar()
        self.z = Tk.StringVar()
        self.w = Tk.StringVar()

    ...
        x_label = ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self.x)
        y_label = ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self.x)
        z_label = ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self.x)
        w_label = ttk.Label(self, textvariable=self.x)
    ...

    def set_values(self):
        self.x.set(some.list[0])
        self.y.set(some.other_list.last_index)
        self.z.set(some.list_total_entries)
        self.w.set('herro worr')
...
```

TestPage inherets from `Tk.Frame`. I believe I 'instantiate' the `TestPage` object when I call `show_frame()` in the main `Application` class, which inherets from `Tk`:

```
# ***** Tkinter Gui classes *****
# Main container, called by app.gui.Application() in main.py
class Application(Tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        Tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)

        container = Tk.Frame(self, name='container')
        container.pack(side="top", fill="both", expand=True)

        container.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        container.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)

        self.frames = {}

        for F in (EntryPage, TestPage):
            frame = F(container, self)
            self.frames[F] = frame
            frame.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")

        self.show_frame(EntryPage)

    # ***** Change view/frame *****
    def show_frame(self, cont):
        frame = self.frames[cont]
        frame.tkraise()

    # ***** Open file *****
    def open_file(self):
        functions.load_file()

...
```

I would like to call `set_values()` from my existing `load_file` function which is in a seperate `functions` module. I call `load_file()` to do some populating of graphs, and to parse the file selected for openening.

```
...
def load_file():
    ...
    if file_name:
        gui.TestPage.set_values()
    ...
...
```

When I try I get the error:

> TypeError: unbound method set_values() must be called with TestPage instance as first argument (got nothing instead)

I need to call the method on the instantiated instance of TestPage, but I do not understand what parameter to supply to `set_values()` to indicate `self` or the current instance of `TestPage`. In the `Application` class I thought I was instantiating `TestPage` as `frame` in the line `frame = F(container, self)`. But I have not been able to reference `set_values()` using `frame` either.

I am not even sure this is the best way to do it. I tried to replace the method with binds, events, and also `@classmethod` and `@staticmethod`, but with no real succes. Should I be using an abstract method for this?

Comment: What? Where are you expecting `parser` to appear from? Do you ever actually *instantiate* a `TestPage`?

Comment: I use a Application class which inherets from tk, and use a dictionary and a seperate method to switch between frames. The 'parser' is a third module already implemented, it 'parses' a file for the values I would like to assign to the `StringVar()` an puts them in different lists, sorry i could have mentioned this :)

Comment: @jonrsharpe I have edited my question and removed the reference to parser, and tried to indicate That TestPage is in fact instantiated. I thought this detail was not important to the question. Everything else than the specific problem in the question you may assume works correctly. I do not understand the downvote, but thank you for trying to help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The values you are changing are attributes of an object, so you need to change them via the instance. In other words, don't pass something to the "self" parameter of a class or abstract function, simply call the function on the object itself.

For example:

```
...
testfile = TestPage(...)
...
load_file(testpage)
...

def load_file(page):
    ...
    page.set_values()
```

Comment: Thank you so much, I believe I am now on the right path, however not quite there yet... I have updated my question to give you a better picture of the mechanics, my project Is based on an online example, and I'm struggling with the OOP side of things. Basically, I (think) I know I'm instantiating the `TestPage` when i show the frame, but I cannot figure out how to reference the current frame being shown. Thank you for taking the time, I think I should have asked the question better from the beginning :)